# Vaadin 7 loading javascript libraries bad performance

Tags: javascript, vaadin, vaadin7

I am using the @JavaScript annotation to load javascript libs into my AbstractJavaScriptComponent, but when many libraries are included , the application takes a long time trying to load these javascript files

Is there a way to only load these js files once for the whole application not each time the UI loads ? or is there is another way to load these js files but with better performance ?

Comment: Are the JS libraries "static" url's? If yes, you can set the caching headers to refresh after a few hours, or if you version them, to not expire at all. That way they won't be reloaded

Comment: I don't know how this can be done using Vaadin. I appended all JS files into one , the performance got really better, I think the performance issue was in opening and closing the files, these operations took a lot of time , so having everything in one file solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the [YUI Compressor Maven Plugin](http://alchim.sourceforge.net/yuicompressor-maven-plugin/index.html)?

Loading a lot of javascript libraries is always going to take a toll on performance. By concatenating and compressing the js files into a single file, you should be able to gain *some* performance improvement.

If you are using maven, a plugin like the [YUI Compressor Plugin](http://alchim.sourceforge.net/yuicompressor-maven-plugin/index.html) would be useful.

It has the ability to:

- Aggregate
- Minify
- Obfuscate

Depending on the number of javascript files, you should definitely notice an improvement.